# I have a problem with making sure that no more than 1 instance of a scanner is created when my Scanner class is being called

Tags: java

The scanner is created in one of the constructors but my if-statement isn't working as i intended

```
private boolean inputStreamExists = false;
    public KeyboardScanner(InputStream inputStream) {

        if (!inputStreamExists) {
            scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
            inputStreamExists = true;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Scanner already exists.");
        }

    }
```

This is the constructor I'm reffering to.

I did try making the "inputStreamExists" variable static. But in the provided test program that seemed to make my problems even worse by not letting it create even a single instance of the scanner.
This is my full scanner class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class KeyboardScanner {

    private Scanner scanner;
    private boolean inputStreamExists = false;
    public KeyboardScanner(InputStream inputStream) {

        if (!inputStreamExists) {
            scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
            inputStreamExists = true;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Scanner already exists.");
        }

    }

    public KeyboardScanner() {

        this(System.in);

    }

    public int setInt(String ledtext) {

        System.out.print(ledtext + " ?>");
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        return a;

    }

    public double setDouble(String ledtext) {

        System.out.print(ledtext + " ?>");
        double b = scanner.nextDouble();
        scanner.nextLine();
        return b;

    }

    public String setString(String ledtext) {

        System.out.print(ledtext + " ?>");
        String s = scanner.nextLine();
        return s;

    }
}
```

Any help appreciated since I'm new to programming!

Comment: You can implement the Singleton Design Pattern.

Comment: scanner and  inputStreamExists  are instance variable that mean for each instance of your class there instance for both of them and by making inputStreamExists only static then the first instance of your keyboard will work fine but 2nd 3rd will make scanner be null for them you can use the singleton as Mukit suggest and you do not need the inputStreamExists field check this for design pattern https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/